# Error when trying to create pdf from html using jsPdf

Tags: angular, jspdf

I got a error when i try to create pdf from html using jsPdf. Is there anything wrong with my code?
thanks in advance

**error**

```
ng:///AppModule/TemplateComponent.ngfactory.js:198 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at k (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at r (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at vendor.bundle.js:69421
    at i (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at v (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at x (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at Object.e.fromHTML (vendor.bundle.js:69421)
    at TemplateComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/pages/County/template/template.component.ts.TemplateComponent.ExportToPdf (main.bundle.js:5082)
```

**component.ts**

Only when i click the button to export html to pdf error is throwing.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.scss']
})
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }


  ExportToPdf() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    let content = this.content.nativeElement;
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

    doc.save('report.pdf');
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocalData();

  }

}
```